# Pass a variable to php

Tags: javascript, php

I need to pass variable "x" to php and I don't know how. (I am very new to html. If you need more info tell me please.  THX :D )

```js
function functionT() {
  swal({
      title: "For help",
      text: "Write your phone number here and we will call you:",
      type: "input",
      showCancelButton: true,
      closeOnConfirm: false,
      animation: "slide-from-top",
      inputPlaceholder: "ex: 0711342647"
    },
    function(inputValue) {
      if (inputValue === false) return false;

      if (inputValue === "") {
        swal.showInputError("Try again");
        return false
      }
      x = inputValue;

      swal("", "You were added on our list: " + x, "success");

    });
}
```

Comment: what is the function `swal`?

Comment: @RamRaider It's the [sweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) lib for creating alert prompts.

Comment: it's a sweet alert

Comment: and does `swal` or `sweetalert` have builtin ajax methods? Nothing in the above will communicate with PHP as it is otherwise

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp - a very brief and simple tutorial but should get you going. Google "ajax tutorial", there's a lot of examples

Comment: well if i try to use "x" outside the function will it keep the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working way.

```
function functionT() {
  swal({
  title: "For help",
  text: "Write your phone number here and we will call you:",
  type: "input",
  showCancelButton: true,
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  animation: "slide-from-top",
  inputPlaceholder: "ex: 0711342647"
},
function(inputValue){
  if (inputValue === false) return false;

  if (inputValue === "") {
    swal.showInputError("Try again");
    return false
  }
  x = inputValue;



  swal("", "You were added on our list: " + x, "success");
  phone(x);
});
}
function phone(x){

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                res = xmlhttp.responseText;

            }
        };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "php.php?x="+x, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
```

And php :

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
$phone_nr = $_GET['x'];
fwrite($myfile, $phone_nr);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

php will write in "newfile.txt" the phone number.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript/Jquery is served client side whilst PHP is served server side, that means you cannot add the x value to a php variable until the form/page is posted. Easy work around is to create a hidden input element with id myxinputbox in your form element, add the x value in there -

```
document.getElementById('myxinputbox').value = x;
```

Then, when you post the form, add x to php -

```
$posted_x = $_POST['myxinputbox'];
```

Comment: Undefined index: myxinputbox

Comment: Please share your PHP code and where you are calling it. Did you check if the POST was successful?